# Running SQL Server query in VB.NET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

How would I create a query that returns a column in the database? The SQL select statement is easy. I'm having issues with the VB side.

```
SELECT UserNO 
FROM UserTable 
WHERE UserID = user;
```

I need to then get that UserNO and pass it to another T-SQL stored procedure. How would I go about running a SELECT query and getting the results back in Visual Basic?

Attached is some of my code. The code below adds the user to the DB however the UserNo (INTEGER) is automatically generated by SQL Server as the INSERT statement is run in the insert stored procedure, so I need to pull the UserNO after the user is created.

```
Public conwd As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=*****;Database=*****;User Id=****;Password=****")
Public conwp As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Server=*****;Database=*****;User Id=****;Password=****")

Dim cmdP As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE [dbo].[AddNewUserWestonTemp] '" + user + "'", conwp)
Dim cmdD As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE [dbo].[AddNewUserWestonTemp] '" + user + "'", conwd)

conmp.Open()
conmd.Open()

cmdP.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmdD.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: explain more this is confusing.

Comment: Don't concatenate strings like that, it leaves you wide open to injection. You need to **parametrise** your query/statement.

Comment: You also should wrap your connection and command objects in a USING statement. The way this is coded the connection is left open and your connection pool will get consumed.

Comment: I guess you could use `IDENT_CURRENT( 'table_name' )`.

Answer (score 0):

The Using..End Using blocks close and dispose of your data objects that might contain unmanaged code. The Parameters help prevent SQL injection.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode2()
    Dim newID As Integer
    Dim sql = "Insert Into UserTable (User) Values (@User); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();"
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "Brian Weaver"
            cn.Open()
            newID = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
        End Using
    End Using
    'Use the newID in your next command
    UserStoredProcedure(newID)
End Sub

Private Sub UseStoredProcedure(id As Integer)
    Dim sql = "InsertSomeUserInfo" 'the name of your stored procedure
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your Connection String")
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            'whatever parameter names and types your stored procedure uses
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Salary", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = 50000
            cn.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I would suggest the OP alters the stored procedure to include the `Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();` In lieu of that add it in code directly after calling the Stored Procedure. Actually, I was not sure if they wanted to use a stored procedure or pure code solution. Showed how to use both. Was that really worth a downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cmdP As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("EXECUTE [dbo].[AddNewUserWestonTemp] '" + user + "'" + "; SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int", conwp)

Dim userNo as Integer = cmdP.ExecuteScalar()
```

---

ExecuteScalar retrieves the first line of the result